# Simple Compute-Intensive CUDA Program

Tags: cuda

I'm preparing an acceptance test for a new machine with Nvidia graphics cards and I'd like a simple CUDA program that will fully exercise the GPU for a full day.  The intent is to generate large amounts of heat and ensure the new machine is stable under the load.  I'd like the code to be very easy to compile and run (no dependencies, no large input data sets), and also very easy to verify (small amounts of output).  Also, I'd like it to be command-line only, no GUI (the test will have to be automated).

I was originally thinking of repeatedly running Vector Dot Products of large vectors.  However, that's mostly memory-intensive.  So if the GPUs are constantly waiting on memory accesses, then they probably aren't generating as much heat as they could.

I'm running on a CentOS Linux machine.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: a quick search got me [this](http://wili.cc/blog/gpu-burn.html)

Comment: What is it ?  I can't read that link.

Comment: A Multi-GPU CUDA stress test, currently the second hit on Google for "cuda gpu intensive test". I have not tested it in any way. Quoting the page "My program forks one process for each GPU on the machine, one process for keeping track of the GPU temperatures if available [...] and one process for reporting the progress. The GPU processes each allocate 90% of the free GPU memory, initialize 2 random 1024*1024 matrices, and continuously perform efficient CUBLAS matrix-matrix multiplication routines on them and store the results across the allocated memory."

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which OS you are on.

Ideally, you would want to stress the floating point units, the logic/integer units, the GPU memory, the GPU voltage regulators (VRMs) and the main PSU. I don't think there is any single utility out there that does that.

Memory:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cudagpumemtest/

Integer (?):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cudalucas/

PSU and VRMs (In the past, this program could cause GPUs to run out-of-spec, breaking the card. I don't think that's the case anymore):

http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/

Comment: Yes, Ideally, I'd test all that.  But I'm time-constrained and I'm just going to have to assume that the GPUs work.  My main concern is that the machine will generate too much heat and might become unstable uder load.  I also don't want to try and break the GPUs either, just a simple but realistic test.

Comment: Then I would run FurMark. I wouldn't trust a machine for GPU computing if it can't run FurMark. It will stress the machine under max power load. It's available for Linux.

Comment: Looks like FurMark is Windows only.  I didn't mention it initially, but I need a Linux app.  Also, I need a command-line app as well (no GUI).  Thanks.